# Pointer values changing and memory in C

Tags: c

I'm having a problem in my code where I am using a pointer that points to memory that I want to store in an array of things I call Holder. This program is reading data in from a txt file which is labelled as line.

```
Holder h; 
Holder anArray[numberOfValues];
char* entry = malloc(160*sizeof(char));
int i = 0;

While(Something) {
   If(x happens) {
     char* p = strtok(entry,".")   //Taking off part of a string based on a "."
     h.firstpart = p;
     p = strtok(NULL, " ");       //Grab second part of string.
     h.secondpart = p;
   }
   else {
     anArray[i] = h;
     i++;
   }
```

The problem I’m having is that h.firstpart and h.secondpart are both going to have the same value since they are just pointing to something and not an actual value themselves. When this reaches the last loop all of my values in the array are set to the thing that was on the last line.

Sorry if this is posted somewhere else, please link me if it is. I'm a C rookie and have been searching for a work around for a few hours now. I'm assuming I need to malloc more memory for this and somehow put the values that p points to into that memory? I'm confused on how I would go about doing that for this loop.

This is also homework, but they expect me to know C already so the context of this question does not solve the problem for me in anyway.

Comment: You might need to allocate memory for `entry` for each and every loop.

Comment: It would be nicer if you posted actual C code you tried to run instead of pseudo-code. `If`, `While`, `Something` and `x happens` are not C. You are new to Stack Overflow. Read this: https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx it will help you get better answers for your questions.

Comment: I read through it thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the contents of `entry` get overwritten with each line, you need to copy the values to another location.

The easiest way would be to use `strdup`, which allocates memory for a nul-terminated string and copies it:

```
While(Something) {
   If(x happens) {
     char* p = strtok(entry,".")   //Taking off part of a string based on a "."
     h.firstpart = strdup(p);
     p = strtok(NULL, " ");       //Grab second part of string.
     h.secondpart = strdup(p);
   }
   else {
     anArray[i] = h;
     i++;
   }
```

`strdup` is declared in `<string.h>`

Comment: Thank you! Haha it feels like I spent forever on this for such an easy solution. Thanks again!

Comment: The hard part is usually to figure out what's wrong and why. Experience and a deep understanding is key to coming up with a simple solution. *The Evolution of a Programmer* is a good example of how even the simplest task can be solved the easy way or the hard way. http://www.ariel.com.au/jokes/The_Evolution_of_a_Programmer.html

Answer (score 0):

Be wary of strtok. It modifies the string it's examining.

Let's say your `entry` is a chunk of memory starting at address 1000, and contains the string "abcdef"

```
1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006
a    b    c    d    e    f    g

entry == 1000
```

If you do:

```
h.firstpart = strok(entry, "c");
```

Then `strtok()` will return the first token it finds using 'c' as a delimiter. But it does that by **replacing the 'c' with a NULL!!**

```
1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006
a    b    NULL d    e    f    g

entry == 1000
h.firstpart == 1000 // "ab"
```

When you call `strtok` again, with NULL as the first argument, it returns the next token along, again replacing the delimiter with NULL.

```
h.secondpart = strtok(null, "f");

1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006
a    b    NULL d    e    NULL g

entry == 1000
h.firstpart == 1000 // "ab"
h.secondpart == 1003 // "de"
```

So, h.firstpart and h.secondpart are pointers into your original chunk of memory. They are not equal to each other. But `strtok()` has written NULLS into your memory, which may not be what you want.

To get around this, either make a copy of the memory before letting `strtok` at it, or use something different from strtok.

Comment: This is nitpicking, but you can't safely say that `strtok` will replace c with a NULL. It is just as unsafe to rely on that. The official documentation just says that it may change the string, it doesn't say that it will write NULLs all over the place.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/, This end of the token is automatically replaced by a null-character, and the beginning of the token is returned by the function.  Probably not all over the place, but certainly where the token is in the string.

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked out better for me that it turned the character into null. I just do another check for null and avoid that spot since I don't want the character anyway.